# Handling C# 2.0 Substring function for dynamic entries to avoid error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Tags: vbscript, c#-2.0

I was having below code in VbScript for checking the valid navigation Item.

```
'==============================================
' Function to test if a given item title is valid navigation item or not
' Checks for '. ' in the first 5 characters of the title
'==============================================
Function CheckValidTitle(ByVal Title)
    If Len(Title)=0 Then
        CheckValidTitle=False
        Exit Function
    End if  
    If InStr(Left(Title, 6), ". ")>0 Then
        CheckValidTitle=True
    Else
        CheckValidTitle=False
    End if
End Function
```

As further, I wrote same function logic in C# 2.0, below is the code:

```
public static bool CheckValidTitle(string title)
{
    bool retvalue;
    if (title.Length == 0)
    {
        retvalue = false;
        return retvalue;
    }   
    string partTitle = title.Substring(0, 5);

    if (partTitle.Contains(". "))
    {
        retvalue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        retvalue = false;
    }   
    return retvalue;
}
```

Now if the title is a long name then above C# function works fine for example, If

`title = "FAQ Popup New";`  //then it works fine as it is long having more than 5 characters in it, however if the

`title = "ASPX";` //it fails as the character are less than 5 and gives error **"Index and length must refer to a location within the string."**

As per the requirement the title name will dynamic and it can be of any no of characters. I am little surprised how it was working fine in VBScript as the logic written is same.

I want to always check for first 5 characters having ". " then it is valid title else it is invalid.

Please suggest what can be best solutions for above problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it works in VB is because the `Left` function in VBScript is forgiving: if the string is shorter than the length you specify, it just silently picks the available length.  In C#, the substring function is not forgiving.

To solve your problem, all you need to do is replace your entire function with the following:

```
if( title == null )
    return false;
int i = title.IndexOf( ". " );
return i >= 0 && i < 5;
```

Comment: do we need to check !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) also?

Comment: If the title might be null, then yes, you should. But your code did not check for null, so I decided not to check, either. The case of 'empty' is already handled in my code by the check for i >= 0.

Comment: Yes there can be the case where title can be null, so we need to add this also in our retvalue = i < 5 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title); return retvalue; Please suggest!!

Comment: I edited my answer to provide for the case that the title may be null.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the IndexOf method

```
if (title.Contains(".") && title.IndexOf(".") < 5)
{
  //there is a . in the first 5 characters
}
```

To be safe you should check the string is not null

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) && title.Contains(".") && title.IndexOf(".") < 5)
{
  //the string is not null or empty and there is a . in the first 5 characters
}
```

Comment: This is not correct; if `". "` is *not* found within title, `IndexOf` will return -1, which *is* less than 5, so there will be a false positive.

Comment: My mistake. Added a title.Contains to ensure that the value does exist within the title

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm one solution just clicked in my mind, Please suggest if it best.

```
public static bool CheckValidTitle(string title)
{
    bool retvalue;
    if (title.Length == 0)
    {
        retvalue = false;
        return retvalue;
    }   
    string partTitle = title.Substring(0,Math.Min(title.Length,5));

    if (partTitle.Contains(". "))
    {
        retvalue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        retvalue = false;
    }   
    return retvalue;
}
```

I changed `string partTitle = title.Substring(0, 5);` with `string partTitle = title.Substring(0,Math.Min(title.Length,5));` and it is working fine now.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Yes, this would work.  But see my answer for something much easier.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated then it needs to be. You don't need to take the substring, you just need to know if there is a "." in the first 5 characters, so the IndexOf method is the best to use.